# 1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'test' cleardb

Tags: mysql, navicat, cleardb

I have an issue that when i try to connect to a database in cleardb it gives me this error:

```
1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'test'
```

when it connect via navicat and try to upload new test.sql file to update my database i get the same error.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: User correctly associated with the database?

Comment: Yes, the database exist in the cleardb but my website anable to connect.

Comment: The database may exist, but are you using the correct user to access it?

Comment: Yes, i copy and past the credential from the cleardb.

Comment: In my case the database is not found in the server.

Comment: I'm doing a migration from visual studio and I encounter this error. What I did was Created the database manually then perform my migration. ta-da problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Default root user in MySQL does not have permissions to access outside local host, so you should create a user to be able to do this like:

```
CREATE USER 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "your_password";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEDGES ON test.* TO 'someuser'@'%';
```

Then try connecting with this user

Comment: i can't create a new user in cleardb, and i use what he gives me

Comment: then you need to connect directly with localhost or tunnel into the machine and connect :(

Comment: I'm doing a migration from visual studio and I encounter this error. What I did was Created the database manually then perform my migration. ta-da problem solved :)